# gulp webpack-dev-server changes not applied

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Trying to set up webpack-dev-server using gulp. When a change occurs, webpack-dev-server appears to rebuild the bundle.js file, but if I refresh the page, it'd be still the same. I have to manually compile the bundle.js with webpack, and restart the server every time.

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('webpack-dev-server', function() {
    var compiler = webpack(require('./webpack.config'));
    new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
        contentBase: 'public',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        progress: true,
        inline: true
    }).listen(8000, 'localhost', (err) => {
                if(err) throw new $.util.PluginError('webpack-dev-server', err);
                $.util.log('[webpack-dev-server]', 'http://localhost:8000');
    });
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/js',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ["es2015", "react"]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: 'public',
        inline: true,
        progress: true
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: contentBase was using the disk's root as the project's root instead of the project folder itself. So the path became "F:\public". I changed it to `contentBase: __dirname + 'public'` and it works.